# is it possible to include a css file into just one html tag?

Tags: css, html

I have more than ul list and I am asking if that possible to make every list import a different css file. because it not easy to class all of them with a different class name.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by import?

Comment: It's hard to give each list a class name but it would somehow be easier to import a separate CSS file for each of them?

Comment: are they all in the same html file?

Comment: @madalinivascu I mean to let every tag its style sheets from specified css file

Comment: @EmreTürkiş sure, all in the same html file

Comment: @Juhana Yes I know, thats what I am asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're missing the purpose of CSS.

HTML are your data, with a potential unlimited tags names. CSS is here for provading style to your data, whatever the html tag is.

You can achive what you're trying do with JavaScript, but i really don't push you to do it that way.

With jquery :

```
$("ul").each(function(index) {
      $("head").append("<link href='css/ul"+index+".css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
    });
```

This spinnet add a css file named ul1.css, ul2.css for each UL you got in your page.

Comment: Thanks @Mat , it's smart solution but I'll take your advice.

Comment: You can validate the aswer so ;)

Answer (score 1):

For inline CSS (not external file), you can use `scoped` attribute, but the navigator support is null (http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped)

Search *"scoped polyfill"* on google.

You have some results from github project which you can try it.
https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll use scoped if I didn't found answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use import function:

```
<ul style="@import url('ulx.css');">
```

Comment: Thanks @madakin , I sow it before but not working, I'll check it again